# same query giving different results in different versions of postgresql !

Tags: postgresql

Folks,

I am running given below query in two different server which has different versions of postgresql which gives strange results.

select distinct
"D","E","A","B","F","C","G","H","I","J","K","L"
from ABC
where "L"=1 
group by "D","E","A","B","F","C","G","H","I","L"
order by "A", "B", "C";

Server1: db details->PostgreSQL 8.3.9 on i486-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.3.real (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2
      EXPLAIN OUTPUT OF QUERY:

```
  Unique  (cost=16618.27..16884.84 rows=8202 width=71)
  Sort  (cost=16618.27..16638.78 rows=8202 width=71)
    Sort Key: "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F","G", "H", "I", J, K
     GroupAggregate  (cost=13296.68..16085.07 rows=8202 width=71)
           Sort  (cost=13296.68..13501.71 rows=82011 width=71)
                Sort Key: "A", "B", ""C"", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "L"
                 Seq Scan on exims  (cost=0.00..3236.14 rows=82011 width=71)
                      Filter: ("L" = 1)                         

  Server2: db details->PostgreSQL 7.4.23 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC cc (GCC) 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)

 EXPLAIN OUTPUT OF QUERY:
  Unique  (cost=22.73..22.90 rows=5 width=361)
   Sort  (cost=22.73..22.75 rows=5 width=361)
    Sort Key: "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F","G", "H", "I", J, K, "L"
      HashAggregate  (cost=22.65..22.67 rows=5 width=361)
            Seq Scan on exims  (cost=0.00..22.50 rows=5 width=361)
                Filter: ("L" = 1)
```

for both the servers I am using same input tables with 82011 records and results are
server1: output of that query -> 82011 records
server2: output of that query -> 53146 records

as for as I can see in server 2 uses Hashaggregate method while server1 uses groupaggregate?

can someone explain which one is the server result I should trust?

BR/
Vijay

Comment: Could you post a minimal and complete example that reproduces what you see so that we can also run for ourselves? To create a minimal example remove as many rows from your table and columns from your query as possible while retaining that the query results still differ. To make your example complete, post the create table statement and the insert statement.

Comment: Just show the real explain analyze output. You showed output of a queries where the first returns 8202 rows and the second just 5 rows.

Comment: Your server1 returns all records. Do all rows have "L"=1 on both servers? Could you post 'explain analyze' output instead of plain 'explain'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the databases are running in different locales. Compare the output of

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

on both databases.

It's a fairly common mistake not to set these to the same when upgrading a system, which can lead to opretaions like ORDER BY, DISTINCT and GROUP BY to deliver different resulsts.